# What is the proof behind this identity used in proving the No-Cloning Theorem

Tags: tensor-products, quantum-information

I am trying to follow an elementary proof of the No-Cloning theorem. The source I am using implies that  $\langle \space(\lvert\psi\rangle \otimes  |\psi\rangle) \space | \space (|\phi\rangle\otimes |\phi\rangle)\space \rangle = \langle\psi\rvert\phi\rangle^2$. I have limited experience in tensor calculus and so do not understand how this step is made. Why is this true? Alternatively, if anyone could direct me to a source that explains it that would also be appreciated.
N.B. This identity appears to be implied by the source rather than explicitly stated. If this is incorrect please do say.

Comment: Perhaps you could state the no-cloning theorem? I gather from your tags and your notation that it's related to physics. I have no idea what your notation means, even though it may be standard in physics. I would recommend stating the theorem and defining the notation. If this is not feasible, you should try the physics site.

Comment: @MattSamuel: the Dirac notation makes it harder to read than necessary here. What that means is just $\langle \psi\otimes\psi, \phi\otimes\phi\rangle = \langle\psi,\phi\rangle$. Which is in fact clearly wrong, as can be seen by inserting $\psi' = 2\cdot \psi$ (which would quadruple the LHS but only double the RHS). Surely you mean $\langle \psi\otimes\psi, \phi\otimes\phi\rangle = \langle\psi,\phi\rangle^2$?

Comment: @MattSamuel I think $\langle χ\otimes φ, ξ\otimes ψ\rangle_{\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{I}} := \langle χ,ξ\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \cdot \langle φ,ψ\rangle_{\mathcal{I}}$ is the conventional definition of the inner product on tensor product spaces. I'm just trying to show it's in fact the _only_ consistent definition, but not sure that's possible. It's certainly the most sensible definition though.

Comment: @leftaround You could always take a scalar multiple. If there's anything to prove here there need to be two specific inner products we want to relate.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Apologies I just dropped the square, I believe that is what I mean. I have edited the question now.

Comment: @MattSamuel the no-cloning theorem states that no quantum circuit can clone an arbitrary unknown quantum state. The source gives a proof but in a mathematical format I'm very unfamiliar with, hence the question

Comment: @RLW Usually the equation you wrote is an easy consequence of the definition of the inner product.on the tensor product. Usually it's defined as $\langle a\otimes b,c\otimes d\rangle=\langle a,c\rangle\langle b,d\rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simply boils down to the induced *definition* of the scalar product on a tensor product space<sup>†</sup> of inner-product spaces $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$: if $χ,ξ\in \mathcal{G}$ and $φ,ψ\in\mathcal{H}$, then
$$
  \langle χ\otimes φ, ξ\otimes ψ\rangle_{\mathcal{G}\otimes\mathcal{H}} := \langle χ,ξ\rangle_{\mathcal{G}} \cdot \langle φ,ψ\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}.
$$
*Why* is that the definition? Well, you want this scalar product to have certain properties, which are easily fulfilled by that definition. In particular, both the tensor product and scalar product must be bilinear (or sesquilinear for a complex scalar product). This already pins the definition largely down to the one given above, but I don't think it can uniquely determine the prefactor.

You can easily derive that exact definition though if you consider baseis $\{g_i|i\in\mathscr{I}_\mathcal{G}\}\subset \mathcal{G}$ and $\{h_k|k\in\mathscr{I}_\mathcal{H}\} \subset \mathcal{H}$. These straightforwardly induce a basis of $\mathcal{G}\otimes\mathcal{H}$ as
$$
  \{g_i\otimes h_k | i\in\mathscr{I}_\mathcal{G},k\in\mathscr{I}_\mathcal{H}\}.
$$
Now, we usually want all baseis to be orthonormal with respect to the inner products on the corresponding space. For the tensor product, this means:
$$
  \langle g_i\otimes h_k,\, g_j\otimes h_l\rangle \stackrel!= δ_{ij}⋅δ_{kl}.
$$
Therefore (written in [summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation))
$$\begin{align}
  \langle χ\otimes φ, ξ\otimes ψ\rangle_{\mathcal{G}\otimes\mathcal{H}}
    =& \langle χ_i g_i\otimes φ_k h_k, ξ_jg_j\otimes ψ_lh_l\rangle
  \\=&  χ_iφ_k\bar ξ_j\bar ψ_l \cdot \langle g_i\otimes h_k, g_j\otimes h_l\rangle
  \\=&  χ_i\bar ξ_j \cdot φ_k\bar ψ_l \cdot δ_{ij}\cdot δ_{kl}
  \\=&  χ_i\bar ξ_jδ_{ij}\cdot φ_k\bar ψ_l δ_{kl}
  \\=&  \langle χ_i g_i, ξ_jg_j\rangle\cdot \langle φ_kh_k,ψ_l h_l\rangle
  \\=&  \langle χ, ξ\rangle_{\mathcal{G}}
          \cdot \langle φ,ψ\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}.
\end{align}$$

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Of course, this definition doesn't yet cover the entire space: a general vector in a tensor product can only be written as a *sum* over such $χ\otimes φ$-pairs, but the extension follows readily from the sesquilinearity property.</sub>